# id not set on nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I have 2 models Order and OrderItem. On Order#new I nested a new OrderItem. When I create the order it gets saved but not the OrderItem. Looks like the order_id is not set in OrderItem.

```
Order has_many :order_items
accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_items, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:product_id].blank? } 
attr_accessible :id, :date, :note, :client_id, :order_items_attributes
```

In OrderItem

```
belongs_to :order 
attr_accessible :product_id, :order_id, :quantity, :color
validates_presence_of :product_id, :order_id, :quantity
```

In my View

```
<%= nested_form_for @order do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :order_items do |item| %>
    <%= item.label :product_id %> <%= collection_select(:order_item, :product_id, Product.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Select Product') %><br/>
    <%= item.label :quantity %> <%= item.number_field :quantity, :value => '1', :min => '1' %><br />
    <%= item.label :color_id %> <%= collection_select(:order_item, :color_id, Color.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Select Color') %>
    <%= item.link_to_remove "Remove this item" %>
  <% end %>
 <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add an item", :order_items %></p>
<% end %>
```

Server log returns `"order"=>{"client_id"=>"1", "note"=>"efewfwe", "order_items_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"quantity"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Order", "order_items"=>{"order_id"=>""}, "order_item"=>{"product_id"=>"12", "color_id"=>"4"}}`

Not sure what the first zero means but order_id is nil

Comment: What does your create method in the Order Controller look like?

Comment: Post the source of action where order is saved. You can inspect order object by assigning order attributes `order.attributes = params[:order]` and then checking whats wrong with order instance.

Comment: @janders223 `class OrdersController < InheritedResources::Base

 def new
   @order = Order.new
   1.times { @order.order_items.build }
 end

end`

Comment: @Hck Not sure what you mean by that nor where this should go `order.attributes = params[:order]` I posted my Order controller above

Answer (score 0):

You are associating OrderItem as `has_many :order_items` with an s. Your model is OrderItem. To use the pluralized version as order_items, you need to set `:inverse_of => :order_item` on your has_many association.

Comment: this is what I get with inverse `Could not find the inverse association for order_items (:order_item in OrderItem)`

Comment: Replace `:inverse_of => :order_item` with `:inverse_of => :order`

Comment: Whoops! That's what I get for answering questions tired. The `:inverse_of => :order_items` needs to go on the `belongs_to` in the order item model for my example to work.

Comment: no effect, in best case I get nil order_id. I am now using a different model Item and set up the same relationship `Order has_many :items and Item belongs_to :order` In my Order controller I have def `new
   @order = Order.new
   1.times { @order.items.build }
 end` but order_id is not set (order_id is accessible). In console when I do Order.first.items.new then order_id gets passed